# React native scroll to on Modal

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I work actually on a picker component which needs to be at center on the middle value by default.
I have created a modal with a ScrollView with ref and use the scrollTo function view on this exemple: https://snack.expo.io/SkileGr9X

Tried all but got this error :

> Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined

Does someone have any tip?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal,TouchableHighlight,View, StyleSheet,ScrollView,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Icon,Picker, Form, Text,Left, Body, Right, Title,Button,List, ListItem} from "native-base";

const Mystyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{

  },
  btnSelect:{
    borderColor:'#a1a1a1',
    borderWidth:1,
    padding:5,
    margin:10,
    height:33
  },
  placeholderSelect:{
    color:'#a1a1a1',
  },
  valueSelect:{
    color:'black',
  }
});

let scrollYPos = 0;
var itemsArray = [];
for(let i=0; i < 90;i++){
  itemsArray.push(i);
}

export default class Selects extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items:itemsArray,
      modalVisible: false,
      isLoading:false,
      selectValue:'',
      placeholder:'placeholder',
      type:'int'
    }
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});

    scrollYPos = this.state.screenHeight * 1;
    this.scroller.scrollTo({x: 0, y: scrollYPos});
  }

  selectItem = (item) =>{
    this.setState({
      selectValue:item,
      modalVisible:false
    });
    this.props.returnSelect(item);
  }

  render(){

  const { selectValue,items,placeholder } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={Mystyles.container}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          presentationStyle='formSheet'
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
            <Header>
              <Left>
                <Button transparent onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(false);}}>
                  <Icon name='arrow-back' />
                </Button>
              </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Title>Header</Title>
                </Body>
              <Right />
            </Header>
            <ScrollView ref={(scroller) => {this.scroller = scroller}}>
              <List dataArray={items}
              renderRow={(item) =>
                <ListItem onPress={() => {this.selectItem(item);}} selected={selectValue == item}>
                <Left>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </Left>
                <Right>
                  <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                </Right>
                </ListItem>
              }>
              </List>
            </ScrollView>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={Mystyles.btnSelect}
          underlayColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text style={selectValue ? Mystyles.valueSelect : Mystyles.placeholderSelect}>{selectValue ? selectValue : placeholder}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My code ? for me only the link for exemple work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Button transparent onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(false);}}>
```

When you press this button, Modal gone so you can scroll when view gone. You have to check:

```
if(this.state.modalVisible){
   scrollYPos = this.state.screenHeight * 1;
   this.scroller.scrollTo({x: 0, y: scrollYPos});
}
```

BTW screenHeight is a const, don't use state.